# Grep pattern and select portion of a after a matching pattern

Tags: awk

Grep pattern and select portion of a line after a matching patterns 41572: 90000: and 90002:

**input**

```
hyt : generation
str : 122344
stks : 9000233
dhy : 9000aaaa
sjyt : hist : hhh9000kkk
Count ch : 41572:47149-47999/2(14485-14910) 41584:47149-47999/2(14911-15449) 90000:47919-47999/2(15447-15477) 90002:47919-47999/2(15478-15418) 
drx : 12345
```

here the code used

```
awk '
{
  flag=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){
       flag=1
       printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
!flag
'   Input_file
```

**with the code above from Mr. RavinderSingh13, I got the following output**

```
hyt : generation
str : 122344
stks : 9000233
dhy : 9000aaaa
sjyt : hist : hhh9000kkk
41572:47149-47999/2(14485-14910) 90000:47919-47999/2(15447-15477) 90002:47919-47999/2(15478-15418) 
drx : 12345
```

**I need the following output desired**

```
hyt : generation
str : 122344
stks : 9000233
dhy : 9000aaaa
sjyt : hist : hhh9000kkk
Count ch : 41572:47149-47999/2(14485-14910) 90000:47919-47999/2(15447-15477) 90002:47919-47999/2(15478-15418) 
drx : 12345
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear, could you please be more clear in your question , what is the logic behind the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution as per OP's new question.

```
awk '{flag="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){flag=1;printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)}}} !flag'
```

OR

```
awk '
{
  flag=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){
       flag=1
       printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
!flag
'   Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following(though not fully clear going by as per shown sample output only).

```
awk 'NF>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)}};next} 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
NF>1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){
      printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk '
NF>1{                                                    ##Checking if NF is greater than 1.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                                    ##Using for loop to go through from value 1 to till value of NF.
    if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){    ##Checking if value of fields is either 41572 OR 90000 OR 90002 then do following.
      printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)                    ##Print the field value in case above condition is TRUE with NEW line if i==NF or space if not.
    }
  }
  next                                                   ##Next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                                        ##1 will print all edited/non-edited lines here.
' Input_file                                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: RavinderSingh13, yes exactly is the output i need to get..No easy to explain the logic..

Comment: @OXXO, writing explanation will add it in few mins.

Comment: @OXXO, please check now and let me know if any queries.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, tks a lot the code works perfectly for the first input example. Is there the chance you add or modify your code to works with Example2 input and get output desired,

Comment: @OXXO, please check my EDIT now.

Comment: RavinderSingh13, The update code for example2 works also, but it dont sow the part "Count ch : " it deletes the initial part of the string.. Please can u fix it .. Thanks a lot...  awk '{flag="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){flag=1;printf"Count ch : "("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)}}} !flag'

Comment: @OXXO, sorry didn't get it, please be clear in your requirement and do not change your requirements frequently, try to mention them in single shot itself in your post itself.

Comment: @OXXO, As already mentioned it is not good to change requirement these many times, you should mention it in single time itself, please open a new question for same and let me know then.